# How to get previous tag (td) child attribute value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get previous td child attribute value using jquery? I am getting undefined while using my code, can you suggest or find whats wrong in my code.

This is my code, I am trying to get the attribute of previous td child from current td input, kindly see the below and suggest me the solution.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head><title>I am a beginner</title></head>
<body>
<table><thead/><tbody>
<td><input name="1sttextbox" type="text" value="10/22/2015" id="1"/></td>
<td><input name="2ndtextbox" type="text" value="10/23/2015" id="2"/></td>
<td><input name="3rdtextbox" type="text" value="10/21/2015" id="3"/></td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {
var input=$("input[type='text']");
input.blur(function() {
    var val1=$(this).val();
    var val2 = $(this).closest('td').prev('td input').attr('value');
    alert(val1);
    alert(val2);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` with result returned by prev, instead of using descendant selector syntax in prev. Your code alose does not have closing }) for blur handler.

```
var val2 = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('input').attr('value');
```

As you are binding element to all inputs, the first input wont have prev input so you need to take care of that as well.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mdatv80e/2/)**

To check if you get the prev element you can use type of to identify if you get undefined.

```
console.log(typeof val2 == 'undefined' ? 'no previous element' : val2);
```

Comment: It can be `.val()` instead of `attr('value')` :)

Answer (score 1):

Created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/4qnukscf/)

```
$(function() {
var input=$("input[type='text']");
input.blur(function() {
    var val1=$(this).val();
    var val2 = $(this).closest('td').prev().find("input").attr('value');
    alert(val1);
    alert(val2);
    return false;
}) });
```

Edited the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/4qnukscf/1/) to check if the input is first td so that undefined is not displayed

```
$(function() {
var input=$("input[type='text']");
input.blur(function() {
    var val1=$(this).val();
    alert(val1);
    if ( $(this).closest('td').index() > 0 )
    {
       var val2 = $(this).closest('td').prev().find("input").val();
       alert(val2);
    }
    return false;
}) });
```

Comment: @newbeee thanks, don't forget to upvote and approve/select the answer

Comment: did we need to include  td in prev()?

Comment: @newbeee In this case - no. You also need not event use closest(), event parent() would do.

Comment: but I need specific tag child attribute, so it is necessary to include the tag inside right?

Comment: @newbeee no, since in your case the parent will always be one - td.

Answer (score 1):

You can get previous input value like:

```
 var val2 = $(this).parent('td').prev('td').children('input').val();
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3f5L4f0/)

Answer (score 1):

Try either adding closing `</thead>` or removing `<thead>` , including `})` at close of `$(function() {})` ; using `$("> input", this.parentElement.previousElementSibling)` to select previous `input` element . Note , if `input` is at index `0` would return `undefined` ; included check for previous `input` being `undefined` , in which instance , alert `#1` `id`

```js
$(function() {
  var input = $("input[type='text']");
  input.blur(function() {
    var val1 = $(this).val();
    var val2 = $("> input", this.parentElement.previousElementSibling);
    alert(val1);
    alert(val2.length && val2.val() || this.id);
    return false;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>I am a beginner</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <td>
        <input name="1sttextbox" type="text" value="10/22/2015" id="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="2ndtextbox" type="text" value="10/23/2015" id="2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="3rdtextbox" type="text" value="10/21/2015" id="3" />
      </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```